# Cloning a row in a table without breaking a button in the row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a beginner currently trying to learn how to code, and my current project is to renovate a website. The website needs a table with an inbuilt save/edit function, which I have already implemented, but it also needs an "add new row" function which I can't seem to get to work. Does anyone know how I might be able to clone a row in my table, whilst keeping the button functional? a previous attempt managed to clone the row, but the button broke. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Here is the code i'm currently working with in fiddle:

HTML:

```
  <table id="tableone" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class="col1">Seminar Name</th>
  <th class="col2">Seminar Date</th>
  <th class="col3">Download Link</th>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="del">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="del" id="tablerow">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button class="addnewrow">Add New Row</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT: 
Frameworks/extensions: jQuery 1.11.0

```
$('.editbtn').click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
});
if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
$this.html('Save');
tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
} else {
$this.html('Edit');
tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
}
});
$('.addnewrow').click(function() {
var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$clone.find('input').val('');
$tr.after($clone);
});
```

Note: for some reason, the button to clone the previous row just stopped working altogether, and the code for the new row seems to have broken the "save" and "edit" code. Additionally, would it be possible to hide the "save" and "edit" buttons so that only people with admin perms can see/interact with them?

Comment: What errors do you get in the browser's console? You're coding in jQuery, have you included jQuery?

Comment: It's because of your js code after click Add new row. `var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');` Closest is find the ancestor, while your button is outside the table.

Comment: Which row do you want to clone on click of  `.addNewRow` button

Comment: but if i try to implement the button as part of the table, the button just breaks and turns into text. how would I be able to clone the button with the row?

Comment: So you have to use the right jquery function to find exactly the table, like `next()`, `find()` or `sibling()`

Comment: @IshanMahajan I'm trying to clone the second row, but if the code can clone the code behind the rows/button, that shouldn't matter because you would be able to edit what's inside the table.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mdwrshga/ Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @TylerBean yes, but as you can see, the buttons break after cloning.

Comment: I see. The problem here is that the handler for `.editbtn` click doesn't bind into the newly created element. For this case, you have to bind event handler to the root element (in this case, `table`), then it will run for all descendants matching (`.editbtn`). Here is the code. https://jsfiddle.net/mdwrshga/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to clone the button and it's click event and callback，so you should use the event proxy，your code doesn't work：

```
$('.editbtn').click(function() {});
```

instead modify to:

```
$('#tableone').on('click', '.editbtn', function() {});
```

and last modify the `.addnewrow`:

```
var $tr = $("#tableone").find("tr:last");
```

```js
$('#tableone').on('click', '.editbtn', function() {
var $this = $(this);
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
});
if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
$this.html('Save');
tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
} else {
$this.html('Edit');
tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
}
});
$('.addnewrow').click(function() {
var $tr = $("#tableone").find("tr:last");
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$clone.find('input').val('');
$tr.after($clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableone" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class="col1">Seminar Name</th>
  <th class="col2">Seminar Date</th>
  <th class="col3">Download Link</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="del">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="del" id="tablerow">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button class="addnewrow">Add New Row</button>
```

Comment: @ChunHo Ok, I modified and made a example, have a try , is that meet your need?

Comment: Ah, thanks. this solved the problem, I didn't realise that the changes had to apply to both functions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code add new row will copy your last row and append it to the table.To solve your problem just bind the click event using document. Even on click might not work sometimes but this will always do.

```js
$(document).on("click",".editbtn",function() {
console.log("Edit called");
var $this = $(this);
var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').filter(function() {
return $(this).find('.editbtn').length === 0;
});
if ($this.html() === 'Edit') {
$this.html('Save');
tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
} else {
$this.html('Edit');
tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
}
});
$('.addnewrow').click(function() {
var $tr = $("#tableone").find("tr:last");
var $clone = $tr.clone();
$clone.find('input').val('');
$tr.after($clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableone" border="2" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th class="col1">Seminar Name</th>
  <th class="col2">Seminar Date</th>
  <th class="col3">Download Link</th>
  <tbody>
  <tr class="del">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="del" id="tablerow">
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td contenteditable="false"></td>
  <td>
  <button class="editbtn">Edit</button>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
  <button class="addnewrow">Add New Row</button>
```

Comment: That works just like @tylerbean 's code, but as with his code, the button breaks after cloning the row.

Comment: What is the meaning of button breaks here.

Comment: as in, it clones the row along with the button, but the button does not work like the original button does.